# Boundary and intersection identity $(\bigcap S_k)\cup(\bigcap \partial S_k)=(\bigcap S_k)\cup \partial(\bigcap S_k)$

Tags: general-topology

I would like to prove the following identity
$$\tag{*}
\left(\bigcap S_k\right)\cup\left(\bigcap \partial S_k\right)=\left(\bigcap S_k\right)\cup \partial\left(\bigcap S_k\right)
$$
using only set theory and the following properties of the map $\partial:\mathcal{P}(X)\to \mathcal{P}(X)$, and $S,T\in\mathcal{P}(X)$:

1. $\partial \varnothing=\varnothing$
2. $\partial S=\partial(X-S)$,
3. $\partial\partial S\subseteq \partial S$,
4. $S\cap T\cap \partial(S\cap T)=S\cap T\cap (\partial S\cup \partial T)$.

> Is (*) correct? Some hint?

I have spent some hour on it, and I'm geometrically (intuition) convinced that it is correct. But although I've solved more similar problems in the last days, this one seems harder to me.

Comment: I've tentatively deleted my answer because I realized that it didn't use just the axioms you gave. Would you please provide more information about how the function $\partial$ is defined? At present $\partial$ could be a function from some collection of sets to $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\emptyset\}$. I will say that if you interpret $\partial$ as the topological boundary then your statement $(*)$ is not true even if there are only two $S_{k}$'s.

Comment: @RobertThingum, I added the information. Yes it should be interpreted as the boundary in topology. Have you an example with two sets, that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true.

With the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ let $ S_1=(0,2)$ and $S_2=(1,3).$ Then $$(S_1\cap S_2)\cup ((\partial S_1)\cap (\partial S_2))=$$ $$=(1,2)\cup (\{0,2\}\cap \{1,3\})=$$ $$=(1,2)\cup \emptyset=(1,2).$$ But $$(S_1\cap S_2)\cup \partial (S_1\cap S_2)=$$ $$=(1,2)\cup \partial (1,2)=(1,2)\cup \{1,2\}=[1,2].$$

Another counter-example is $S_1=\Bbb Q$ and $S_2=\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q.$ Then $S_1\cap S_2=\partial (S_1\cap S_2)=\emptyset,$ but $\partial S_1=\partial S_2=\Bbb R.$

Comment: $\overline S=S\cup \partial S= Int(S)\cup \partial S,$ where $Int(S)$ is the interior of $S$. ..So $(S_1\cap S_2)\cup\partial (S_1\cap S_2)=$ $\overline  {S_1\cap S_2}.$ But two disjoint sets can have a common boundary point. In my 2nd counter-example, $S_1$ is dense and co-dense, so $(\partial S_1) \cap (\partial S_2)$ is the whole space, but $S_1$ and $S_2$ are disjoint so $\overline {S_1\cap S_1}$ is empty.

Comment: ...even trying harder I had no chance to prove it right, if it's wrong! then I have an error in deriving (*). Thank you.

Comment: I remember trying to prove something  in  university homework, where a plus sign had been printed mistakenly for a minus sign, and nearly convincing myself that I had done it.